# Best shortcut management tool for development machine?

Tags: desktop, development-environment

As a developer I had a slew of shortcuts and applications used daily.  Visual Studio 6, 2003, 2005, 2008, SQL Client tools, WinMerge, Notepad++, Synergy, VMware (and lots and lots of VMs, multiple browsers, and on top of all that about 20 shortcuts to important directories, servers, test environments etc...

The Vista start menu is a lifesaver for getting to many of them quickly.  However there are plenty of daily tasks that still require a relatively large amount of work to access (open a folder, jump through a few sub-folders, find a specific file and fire it off.

What tools/applications/utilities do you find to be the most beneficial to providing organized and fast access to all of your most frequently visited tools?

What are some tools that can be embedded on the task bar of Windows that provide similar functionality to drawers in Linux or stacks in OS X?  My current quick-launch bar (and other folders added to the task bar) eat up tons of real estate and insist on opening new explorer windows to display sub-directories, which suffices but is still slow and polutes my desktop.

*...can't wait for tomorrow to get the Win 7 RC and its finally improved task bar*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/). I first heard about it from [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScottHanselmans2007UltimateDeveloperAndPowerUsersToolListForWindows.aspx).

Comment: I've used Launchy in Gnome and wasn't aware it was for windows too.  So far I've only used it with minimal tweaks and usually fallback to Alt-F2 (in Linux) but might need to get a little more familiar with its offerings.

Comment: It essentially lets you define your own shortcut keys through learning. So if you type sql, then hit down arrow and choose enterprise manager, next time you type sql it will be the first in the list. I end up using acronyms for lots of things.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I'm a big fan of [SlickRun](http://www.bayden.com/SlickRun/).  It's basically a command launcher tool, but it's how I launch almost everything.

Comment: Kevin, +1 for arguing for SlickRun.  I have tried a number of the newer command launcher tools (Launchy, Executor), but I keep coming back to SlickRun, simply for its ease of use.

Comment: Even in 2023, I still love the simplicity and the performance of SlickRun.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) from Stardock. It's very clever, and lets you keep your desktop clean and organized, even with lots of shortcuts. Oh, and it's free.

Comment: ooo, havent seen this, looks awesome

Comment: pretty nice so far, and might be a keeper for my most-used shortcuts--but so far my impression is that it's not the solution for holding all ~50 of my shortcuts :-D

Comment: Are you working on a netbook? :-) My desktop has 38 icons on it, and there's lots of room to spare for more if I needed them.

Answer (score 2):

**I love [Humanized Enso](http://www.humanized.com/).**

Their product is free now, although it is no longer developed by the original authors.

There is also a [Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/enso/) that builds on a Enso prototype, which allows you to easily extend it using Python.

**Short summary:**

- Allows you to teach shortcuts to the program
- Has nice features like:

  - Integrated translation...
  - Integrated Google Maps...
  - Integrated dictionary
  - Integrated Google search
  - etc...
- Developed by the same people that are now working on [Mozilla Ubiquity](http://labs.mozilla.com/projects/ubiquity/)

Comment: ahh!  I remember seeing this a while back, but forgot all about it.  I'm playing with it and it might be a pretty big benefit for what I'm after

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty fond of [SlickRun](http://www.bayden.com/SlickRun/)

Answer (score 1):

I use [HotKeyboard](http://www.hot-keyboard.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think Virtual Desktop Manager is a good solution if you are using XP. I dont know there is a simillar microsoft product for windows Vista or not.. :(

Comment: I'm familiar with it but had mostly forgotten about it.  It's nice but my personal fault of not being the best about keeping seperate desktops for seperate purposes usually bites me in the end.  I'm the kind of person who lives in organized disorder/chaos.

Answer (score -1):

Quicksilver style launchers are quite common to accomplish this task. 
You press a keyboard shortcut or click on an icon in the tray, that pops up a window where you can search for your programs, documents, shortcuts, bookmarks, etc.

Check out [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/), its simple, clean and free.